# How to avoid same object instance from modified when reading from cache?

Tags: java

I have an in-memory cache backing a db-call illustrated below. I just ran into a bug because the same instance of `Config` object was being modified when in fact I want to have a "fresh" instance each time (without going to the db).

Questions are

1) What is the best practice to avoid the same object from being modified when loading from a cache?

2) Is it to deep copy the object after reading from cache and use the deep-copied object?

3) If so, what is the easiest way to deep copy an object?

```
public void doStuff(String configId) {
    Config config = someUserCache.get(configId);

    //Modifies config   
    config.getSomeConfig().remove();
}
```

Comment: Ideally, the instances in your cache would be immutable objects. If not, there is no built-in easy mechanism to deep-copy arbitrary objects, you have to come up with a method that works for your data. Some caches serialize the object into a byte array, but obviously there is some cost to that, it does not work with non-serializable classes and does not preserve object graphs across entries (if that is what you need). Since you mentioned "DB access", the ORM frameworks that people like to use should have "Level-2" cache support (and make sure you get session-private instances to play with).